# linked startDate endDate DateTimePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I would like to enable minute after changing hour for time. 

**Current code:**

 Set minDate to 0, so the datetimepicker set to current date and time

 So, if start date 7/5/2019 02:34 PM 

 If i select hour: 3, the minutes field should enable all minutes from 01 - 59.


 **Current problem:** I cannot selected minutes under that current time.

```
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        }).val("");
```

```
$('#endDate').datetimepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        }).val("");
```

I have made some changes to the code that fix the problem in the minutes field.

Examples: 7/5/2019 02:30 PM
I select 3 in hours field, the datetimepicker will close and update minutes field.
When I open again the datetimepicker, the minutes field show 01-59.

The problem now, is I want it to update the minutes field without closing the datetimepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved with:**

```
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
     minDate: 0,
     onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
         $("#endDate").datetimepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
         $("#startDate").datetimepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
     }
}).val("");
```

```
$('#endDate').datetimepicker({
     minDate: 0,
     onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
         var sdSelected = $('#startDate');
         var edSelected = $('#endDate');

         var value = sdSelected.val();

         sdSelected.datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', edSelected.datetimepicker('getDate'));

         if (sdSelected.val() != null) {
             sdSelected.val(value);
         }
    }
}).val("");
```